# aligning a dataGrid in a grid component.

Tags: apache-flex, layout, components, flex4.5

please, in the code below, i would like to align the datagrid in the gridItem with instance 'row5' such that it is align with the other textInput in instances 'row3' and 'row4'?

thanks for any suggestion given..

```
 <mx:Grid paddingTop="4" paddingLeft="4">
    <mx:GridRow id="row1">
        <mx:GridItem>
            <s:Label text="Description:" 
                     paddingTop="5"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem>
            <s:TextArea id="descTI" width="227" height="50"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>

    <mx:GridRow id="row2">
        <mx:GridItem>
            <s:Label text="Name:" 
                     paddingTop="5"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem colSpan="3">
            <s:TextInput id="nameTI" width="227"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>

    <mx:GridRow id="row3">
        <mx:GridItem>
            <s:Label text="Target:" 
                     paddingTop="5"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem colSpan="3">
            <s:TextInput id="targetTI" width="227"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
    <mx:GridRow id="row4">
        <mx:GridItem>
            <s:Label text="Through level:" 
                     paddingTop="5"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem colSpan="3">
            <s:TextInput id="throughLevTI" width="227" height="20"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
    <mx:GridRow id="row5">
        <mx:GridItem colSpan="4">
            <s:Label text="Operand:" 
                     paddingTop="5" />
            <mx:DataGrid id="attrDG">
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="variable" 
                                       width="150"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="level" 
                                       width="150"/>
                </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
</mx:Grid>
```

Comment: Is this markup created by you? Why you need `colSpan="3"` almost in every row when the maximum number of columns is 2?

Comment: the maximum number of columns is 2? i don't understand. does that means that one can't have a colspan greater than 2?

Comment: Comparing to HTML `mx:GridRow` is for `tr` and `mx:GridItem` is for `td` (columns). You haven't rows with `mx:GridItem` count more than 2. So you haven't more than 2 columns.

Comment: is that why the datagrid is not aligned with the other textInput components?

Comment: Don't know. To solve your problem I need to understand the problem. But now I even can't understand things at all. First step is to do existing things right. Then it will be easier to extract and solve the problem.

Comment: in the code, the datagrid juts out and i want to align it with the TextInput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:
Some tweaks in GridItem, colspan and width and you are done.

```
<mx:Grid paddingTop="4" paddingLeft="4">  
    <mx:GridRow id="row1"> 
        <mx:GridItem>        
            <s:Label text="Description:"  paddingTop="5"/> 
        </mx:GridItem>     
        <mx:GridItem>      
            <s:TextArea id="descTI" width="300" height="50"/> 
        </mx:GridItem> 
    </mx:GridRow>    
    <mx:GridRow id="row2">  
        <mx:GridItem>        
            <s:Label text="Name:" paddingTop="5"/>   
        </mx:GridItem>        
        <mx:GridItem>     
            <s:TextInput id="nameTI" width="300"/>  
        </mx:GridItem>   
    </mx:GridRow>   
    <mx:GridRow id="row3">  
        <mx:GridItem>        
            <s:Label text="Target:" paddingTop="5"/> 
        </mx:GridItem>      
        <mx:GridItem> 
            <s:TextInput id="targetTI" width="300"/>     
        </mx:GridItem>   
    </mx:GridRow>    
    <mx:GridRow id="row4"> 
        <mx:GridItem>       
            <s:Label text="Through level:" paddingTop="5"/>  
        </mx:GridItem>        
        <mx:GridItem> 
            <s:TextInput id="throughLevTI" width="300" height="20"/>       
        </mx:GridItem>   
    </mx:GridRow>  
    <mx:GridRow id="row5">   
        <mx:GridItem>  
            <s:Label text="Operand:" paddingTop="5" />  
        </mx:GridItem>   
        <mx:GridItem> 
            <mx:DataGrid id="attrDG">    
                <mx:columns>          
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="variable" width="150"/>           
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="level"           
                                       width="150"/>       
                </mx:columns>       
            </mx:DataGrid>    
        </mx:GridItem>   
    </mx:GridRow> 
</mx:Grid>
```

Comment: is it possible to add another dataGrid horizontally aligned to the dataGrid and the new dataGrid is paddedLeft = 3? if yes, could you modify the code so i have two datagrids horizontally aligned with a gap of 3? thanks

Comment: @Henry you can do this by putting the second datagrid in the another DataGridItem and set the paddingLeft to 3. You then set the colspan of other gridRows to 2.